# Error al cargar un excel en Jupyer con Python porque falta openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, anaconda, openpyxl, conda

Estoy intentando cargar un excel en Jupyer Notebook con Python y me da el siguiente error:

```
ImportError: Missing optional dependency 'openpyxl'.  Use pip or conda to install openpyxl.
```

Sigo estos pasos:

1. Me pide openpyxl y lo instalo con
2. Conda parece que lo instala pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error en Jupyter aunque recargue, reincie el entorno, el ordenador, etc etc

Este es el código que me da pero me sigue dando el mismo error en Jupyter cuando vuelvo a intentar cargar el excel:

```
(base) C:\Users\Oscar>conda install openpyxl
Channels:

- conda-forge
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
    current version: 24.1.1
    latest version: 24.1.2

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda

# All requested packages already installed.
```

Cuando hago el <conda update -n base -c conda-forge conda> no me actualiza Conda a la versión 24.1.2 y me vuelve a decir que existe una versión mas nueva que la 24.1.1

He buscado en las preguntas similares, por internet y, sinceramente, ya no sé que hacer

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.

El problema es que estaba instalando el paquete en un entorno erróneo. Cosas de novato jeje